# Finding equation of a plane parallel to a given line and passing through two given points

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, solid-geometry

If a plane passes through two points:

$A=(1,0,-2)$ and $B=(3,-1,1)$

and is parallel to the line:

$r=(3,-1,5)^T + a(0,2,-1)^T$,

then what is the vector equation of the plane?

I have obtained that the plane must be of the form:

$p=(1,0,-2)^T +\delta_1((1,0,-2)^T-(3,-1,1)^T)+\delta_2((3,-1,1)^T-(x,y,z)^T)$

but I can't determine what direction vectors of the plane are parallel to the direction vector of the line?

e.g

is it true to say $(3,-1,1)^T-(x,y,z)^T=\mu(0,2,-1)$?

Comment: Or is it a linear combination of the direction vectors of the plane is equal to the direction vector of the line? Thanks

Comment: Another approach to the problem would be the following: Since the plane contains $A$ and $B$, it contains the vector $\overline{AB} = \langle 2, -1,3 \rangle$, and since it is parallel to $r$, the plane contains the vector $\langle 0,2,-1 \rangle$.  Take the cross-product to find the normal vector.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I am not familiar with this approach

Comment: Are you saying the equation of the plane becomes $p=(1,0,-2)^T+\delta_1(-2,1,-3)^T+\delta_2(0,2,-1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the plane contain the line $AB$ and the vector director of the line $r$ which is
$\vec{u}=(0,2,-1)$.

the cross product $ \vec{u}\times  \vec{AB}$ gives the normal vector to the plane.

which is

$(-5,2,4)$

so the cartesian equation of the plane has the form

$-5x+2y+4z=D$.

the point $A(1,0,-2)$ is in the plane, so
$-5-8=-13=D$.

Comment: how would you obtain this without using the cross product?

Comment: use determinant(\vec{u},\vec{AB},\vec{AM})=0

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima What is M in AM?

Comment: @JackOfBlades $M$ is a point of the plane with $(x,y,z)$ as coordinates.